# Configuration of Solr Request Handlers in Tomcat

Tags: solr

I a complete noob at solr/java . I have solr 3.6.1 running on Tomcat(Windows) . I am able to get the solr admin page . I want to move ahead with DIH configuration . However the solarconfig.xml is confusing specially the paths for the class of request handlers. The request handler classes are specified as

"solr.SearchHandler" or as "org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler"

I cannot find either of these files either in my solr home directory or solr webapp (under the tomcat webapps folder) . I did find HTML files for these in my solr download (which is placed separately since I just copied the example/solr directory for solr_home and solr.war file for webapp) . Do I need to manually copy these files and if so where and how should my directory structure look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`solr.SearchHandler` class is resolved by the Solr war file. For `org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandler` class you should add the required jar file into the lib directory. Final solr directory should look like :

```
-solr
  +conf
  +data
  -lib
    +apache-solr-dataimporthandler-x.y.z.jar
    +apache-solr-dataimporthandler-extras-x.y.z.jar
  +apache-solr-x.y.z.war
  +solr.xml
```

Also you should add other needed libraries inside the lib folder.

Comment: This structure is for solr home or solr webapp ? Because my conf (containing schema.xml and solarconfig.xml) directory is in solr home .Also how should I specify the path in solarconfig.xml , if you could tell me the path which is prefixed to what is specified  in class attribute for a request handler , it would help me out .

Comment: This is the structure of solr home. You can set path as : <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:/path_to_the_solr/solr/data}. Change path_to_the_solr with absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

For DIH, you need to add the respective jar (apache-solr-dataimporthandler-x.jar) to the lib directory in webapps (Tomcat). Also copy the files in contrib/dataimporthandler/lib to this directory.

Answer (score 0):

Every class files need for the DIH is inculded in the war file which comes with the web app folder. You can use these for your out of box functionalities. If you really want to work around the code for any customization then you can download the release with source code in the repositary.